# Re-draw Charts on Resize

Tags: javascript, charts

After checking the forum I couldn't find anything for the following issue:

I have three charts that are triggered after the user clicks on the below buttons and then, when the window resizes, the chart is drawn again.

```
//Calling the different button clicks   
      document.getElementById('traffBut').onclick = drawTrafficAndResize;
      document.getElementById('convBut').onclick = drawConversionsAndResize;
      document.getElementById('revBut').onclick = drawRevenueAndResize;
      document.getElementById('tranBut').onclick = drawTransactionsAndResize;

    //functions to draw and then redraw on resize
        function drawTrafficAndResize() {
                drawTraffic();
                resizeMode(drawTraffic);
              }
              function drawConversionsAndResize() {
                drawConversions();
                resizeMode(drawConversions);
                }
                function drawRevenueAndResize() {
                drawRevenue();
                resizeMode(drawRevenue);
                }
                function drawTransactionsAndResize() {
                drawTransactions();
                resizeMode(drawTranctions);
                }
   //And this is the resizing function:
      function resizeMode (metric){
      window.onresize = metric;
                                   }
```

For any reason it works for all buttons with the exception of the last one, if you click the last button which runs drawTransactionsAndResize, it draws the chart triggered by the previous button..

For example if I click the traffic button, and then click the transactions button and then resize the screen, it triggers drawTraffic.

It only happens with this last element, the other buttons run the drawing function and then execute the drawing function again on window resize.

I just can't get my head around this, so any help would be much appreciated,

Many thanks
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torches on me:
 resizeMode(drawTranctions);
should be 
 resizeMode(drawTransactions);

Sorry everyone :( and thanks!